# Slider changes Pi to a MachinePrecision number

Tags: manipulate, precision-and-accuracy, slider

## Problem

Consider the following code:

```
DynamicModule[{a = {0, Pi}, b = 4},
  {Slider[Dynamic@b, {a}], Dynamic@b}
]
```

I want a `Slider` which sets `b` to the exact values in `a` (0 and `Pi`). However `b` is set to `3.14159` instead of `Pi`.

The same problem exists also for `Manipulator` and `Manipulate`:

```
Manipulate[b,
  {b, {0, Pi}, ControlType -> Slider}
]
```

Is there a better way to do this than the following workaround?

## Workaround

My current workaround is to use a third variable `c` and `Nearest`:

```
DynamicModule[{a = {0, Pi}, b, c},
  {Slider[Dynamic@b, {a}], Dynamic@b, Dynamic[c = First@Nearest[a, b]]}
]
```

this sets `c` correctly to 0 or `Pi` but it is a bit cumbersome.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your results with Manipulate in MMA 12.2. The variable does get set to Pi. As an aside, using a slider to choose between only two values is very counterintuitive, since a slider naturally suggests a continuum of values. Use another control that explicitly indicates only two values are available (just like the default Manipulate would do with two values given).

Comment: @MarcoB Ok, then I have to test again with Manipulate. My actual usage includes many multiples of Pi. This question is only a minimal example.

Comment: If you want the control variable to only take exact values you need to specify step values that are exact values, e.g., `Manipulate[var, {{var, Pi}, 0, Pi, Pi/16, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]`

Comment: @BobHanlon -- You should add this as an answer.  Simple and elegant, as we have all come to expect from you;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the control variable to only take exact values you need to specify all values including the step value as exact values, e.g.,

```
Manipulate[var, {{var, Pi}, 0, Pi, Pi/16, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this great answer. However my full problem is that I have a list of numbers which may be also {0, Pi, 4.5, 7 Pi} with no repeatable patterns. Do you also have an easier solution for this case?

Comment: @Qbyte - For a slider you need to specify the lower bound, upper bound, and step size. You have not said how the list `{0, Pi, 4.5, 7 Pi}` relates to a slider or what the list is supposed to represent. If you are just trying to select from a list, a `SetterBar` or `RadioButtonBar` or `PopupMenu` may be more appropriate. Provide a complete description of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

```
Manipulate[If[b < Pi, b, Pi], {b, {0, Pi}, ControlType -> Slider}]
```

[image]